# How to save an object with null dbref in mongodb java spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm looking for a solution to save an object with a null dbref in mongodb java spring framework. Consider the following example:

```
@Document
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private B b;

    public A() {
        this.b = null;
    }

    ...
}

@Document
public class B {
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

Now if I instantiate A, i.e. `A a = new A();` and save this object to mongodb via repository, i.e. `aRepo.save(a)`. Then, I have the following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.
```

Is there a way to save an object with a null dbref?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Generally speaking the error you're referring to occurs whenever you try to save an Entity that points to a referenced (non `null`) one that has not been saved yet or does not have an `id` set. Given the code above I cannot reproduce the issue - so I'm curious which version of `spring-data-mongodb` are you using?

Comment: Indeed, I checked the sources and there is a check like id == null? throw exception. My version is <spring.data.mongo.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>

Comment: Hey! I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: unfortunately, the only solution I found is to get rid of the @dbref...

Answer (score 1):

You are using @DBREF, so you need to create object B first to DB. You can do so:

```
B b = new B();
mongoOperations.save(b);

A a = new A();
a.setB(b)
mongoOperations.save(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dbref encapsultes multi collection data fetching in a `FOREGIN KEY` kinda-way. If you're using `@DBRef` on a field it means that you have this entity already stored, so it must have an `@Id`. If you want to just store data in an object without cross-collection reference just remove the `@DBRef` annotation.

For example this is how your data looks in mongodb with `@DBRef`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd1e18ee5adfb64cf7edc5c"),
    "b" : {
        "$ref" : "b",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5bd1e1b7e5adfb65f847159d")
    },
    "_class" : "namespace.A"
}
```

And this is how it looks without `@DBRef`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd1e18ee5adfb64cf7edc5c"),
    "b" : {
        "id" : "someid",
        "anotherfield" : "somevalue"
    },
    "_class" : "namespace.A"
}
```

Here's how to set a dbref field:

```
B b = bRepository.findById("someid").get();
A a = new A();
a.setB(b);
aRepository.save(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only solution is that to remove `@DBref` annotation because `@DBRef` is an annotation that indicates the annotated field is to be stored using a DBRef.

docs: [spring.io - DBRef](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DBRef.html)

Answer (score -1):

As variant you can create NullObject like:

```
public final static B NULL_B = new B("");
```

and use it instead of null

```
public A() {
    this.b = NULL_B;
}
```

Comment: And spring-data add only one empty document to B collection for all calling save() method with NullObject

Comment: why would you ever do that? There's no problem with  `this.b = null`, problem is  `this.b = new B()` because it's not an initialized document.